# Sybase "power" function returns an empty result set (Truncation error)

Tags: sql, sybase

I've been trying to implement a formula for some reporting in a Sybase 15.7 SQL query, I was getting some strange results so I tried breaking down the query and running it as single selects.

```
select (1+(8.0/12))
```

Result: **1.66667**

All as expected so far

```
select power(1+(8.0/12), 1)
```

Result: **1.66667**

Still fine (it also works for an integer raised to an integer power)

```
select power(1+(8.0/12), 2)
```

Empty result set....

Why does the power function fail in this case?

Checking the logs I'm getting a warning saying "truncation error occurred" which I assume means it doesn't have enough precision to handle the result of the power function. However I can't find anything online about how to handle that error or make it give me the best approximation it can of the result...

How do I calculate power(1+(8.0/12), 60) in Sybase? (The eventual formula needs the exponent to be 60 or even higher, but Sybase falls over with the exponent just being 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that it works if both inputs are floating point.

In other words, this works:

```
select power(1+(8.0/12), 60.0)
```

Comment: In SAP ASE 16 they still have the same problem: SELECT POWER(123.45, 2.0) properly returns one row/value, while SELECT POWER(123.45, 2) returns nothing.